# How to get the number of elements in a linked list?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, size

I have a method called getLength

```
    public int getLength(LinkedList<Boolean> numbers){

    int length = numbers.size();
    return length;
    }
```

So it passes in a linked list of boolean values and names it numbers. What I'm trying to do is just get the length of the linked list, how many elements there are in it.

Am I using `.size()` correctly in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, .size() will return the number of items in the linked list:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#size()

Answer (score 0):

On the Java API, we can read :

> size() :
>   Returns the number of elements in this LinkedList.

So, I think that's what you want to get.

Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html